# How can i create and add an image to my page on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, web

Im adding a small function to my page where when you click a button it adds the corresponding image on the page after a certain class.

I have tried several approaches to this 'basic' problem. i have been working on this problem for two days now with no luck.

After clicking my buttons to get some interaction, I quickly recieve the 'Aw, Snap!' error from google. I know my computer can handle grabbing few images and displaying them on the page.

here is a part of my code thats most likely causing the trouble. Ive tried taking this part out of my code out and it helped. I didnt get the error message anymore, but it obviously stopped performing what i wanted it to.

```
  var elem;
    function placeImg(type) {

    //creates and sets attributes for an img
    elem = document.createElement("img");
    elem.setAttribute("src", type+".png");
    elem.setAttribute("height", "50");
    elem.setAttribute("width", "40");
    elem.setAttribute("alt", type +' logo image');

    //puts image after the class original, its an input area
    //there is only one class tag with the name original
    $('#original').after(elem);


 }


 // when an ids with these names are clicked
 $("#arrow, #barber,  #gas, #lion, #none").click(function() {

    //checks if the current input area has a length of 12 or less
    if($('#'+findCurrentEditor()).val().length <=12){
        placeImg(this.id);  //places the image somewhere
    } 

 });
```

Id appreciate anyone willing to try and help.

Thanks!

Comment: You didn't say what error you're getting.

Comment: Include HTML  in a [mcve]

Comment: @Carcigenicate i get the 'Aw, Snap!' error from google

Comment: looks like this : https://www.xtremerain.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/screenshot-aw-snap-error-chrome.jpg                                 i dont see anything wrong in the console  @Carcigenicate

Comment: @user2275365 Press "learn more".

Comment: @Carcigenicate thank you! i have already read through that document. I have enough memory on my PC as it advices me to check that. I also dont have any other program or tabs open.

Comment: @Carcigenicate turns out my image files were corrupted, couldnt even open them in mspaint

Comment: @user2275365 I'd actually just expect it to not load the image. Odd it prevented the page from loading. Oh well.

Comment: @Carcigenicate its really strange it opens the image badly on irfanview, open well but with huge dimension on chrome, and doesnt even open in mspaint. Few of the corrupt image fixer programs i tried didnt work on fixing my images

Answer (score 0):

I only help you in creating image with jQuery and add it into a div by clicking a button. The rest, you can figure it out since it just some common logic.

```
$(".btn").on("click", function() {
    var $image = $('<img />').attr({
        src: 'https://c7.staticflickr.com/6/5820/30597229222_119e91f7e4_k.jpg',
        height: "300",
        width: "400"
    })
    $("div#img-wrapper").html($image);
});
```

see [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/trungkim2201/kckwyp2b/)

Comment: hey thanks a lot for this! i see your demo and it works as i wanted it to. like you said, i can fix my problem with your answer :) could you please explain to me how your solution differs from mine, which doesn't work.

Comment: turns out my image files were corrupted, couldnt even open them in mspaint